# How to use the IconMarkupExtension in nuxt js autodesk forge viewer?

Tags: nuxt.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I was trying to use the IconMarkupExtension by following the example,

https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/placing-custom-markup-dbid

I tried to convert this in to nuxt js and use it. But when the viewer is loaded I've the toolbar created and tooltip displayed but when I click on that toolbar no markups are being added.

Can someone correct my code such that it works in a nuxt based app. I'll leave my sample code below.

//index.vue

```
    <template>
  <div>
    <div id="forgeViewer"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  components: {

  },  
  data(){
    return{

    }
  },
  mounted(){
      this.initAutodesk();
  },
  methods:{
    async initAutodesk(){
    var htmlDiv = document.getElementById('forgeViewer');
    const IconMarkupExtension = await import('./extensions/IconMarkupExtension.js').then(mod=>mod.default)
    Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('IconMarkupExtension', IconMarkupExtension);
    const viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.GuiViewer3D(htmlDiv,{ extensions: ['IconMarkupExtension'] });
    window.viewer = viewer;
       window.viewer.loadExtension('IconMarkupExtension', {
            button: {
                icon: 'fa-thermometer-half',
                tooltip: 'Show Temperature'
            },
            icons: [
                { dbId: 1942,   label: '300&#176;C', css: 'fas fa-thermometer-full' },
                { dbId: 10876,    label: '356&#176;C', css: 'fas fa-thermometer-full' },
                { dbId: 2648,  label: '450&#176;C', css: 'fas fa-thermometer-empty' },
                { dbId: 2228,                         css: 'fas fa-exclamation-triangle' },
            ],
            onClick: (id) => {
                viewers.select(id);
                viewers.utilities.fitToView();
                switch (id){
                    case 2228:
                        alert('Sensor offline');
                }
            }
        })
    var options = {
        env: 'AutodeskProduction',
        api: 'derivativeV2',  // for models uploaded to EMEA change this option to 'derivativeV2_EU'
        getAccessToken: function(onTokenReady) {
          var token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Imp3dF9zeW1tZXRyaWNfa2V5In0.eyJzY29wZSI6WyJjb2RlOmFsbCIsImRhdGE6d3JpdGUiLCJkYXRhOnJlYWQiLCJidWNrZXQ6Y3JlYXRlIiwiYnVja2V0OmRlbGV0ZSIsImJ1Y2tldDpyZWFkIl0sImNsaWVudF9pZCI6Ikp2Vk40bzdBQ0V0ZE81TVpnZ21QMk9WM1RoNFJnRW54IiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9hdXRvZGVzay5jb20vYXVkL2p3dGV4cDYwIiwianRpIjoiMkhNbElFTnhpVEthb3VueXpPN2NTUVNFeDhvMWJDWnlDYWs5WGVEM2c5V0xjbldRY3gwdXRsendhcG1tS3lkRyIsImV4cCI6MTU5MTE4NjIyN30.wmYOe6nZEo9IpWxVLtF1E6FUR4WRjNgF4BjNshzCZvI';
          var timeInSeconds = 3600; // Use value provided by Forge Authentication (OAuth) API
          onTokenReady(token, timeInSeconds);
        }
      };
    Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function() {
      var startedCode = viewer.start();
      if (startedCode > 0) {
        console.error('Failed to create a Viewer: WebGL not supported.');
        return;
      }
      console.log('Initialization complete, loading a model next...');
    });
    var documentId = 'urn:dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6ZmFjaWxpb25ld2NsaWVudGJ1Y2tldC9yYWNfYWR2YW5jZWRfc2FtcGxlX3Byb2plY3QucnZ0';
    Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, this.onDocumentLoadFailure);
    function onDocumentLoadSuccess(viewerDocument) {
        var defaultModel = viewerDocument.getRoot().getDefaultGeometry();
        viewer.loadDocumentNode(viewerDocument, defaultModel);
        viewer.addEventListener( Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, event=>{
           console.log(event.dbIdArray.length);
        })
    }
  },
  onDocumentLoadFailure() {
      console.error('Failed fetching Forge manifest');
    },
  }
}
</script>

<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
  }
  #forgeViewer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #F0F8FF;
  }
</style>
```

/pages/extensions/IconMarkupExtension.js

```
class IconMarkupExtension extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extension {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this._group = null;
        this._button = null;
        this._icons = options.icons || [];
    }

    load() {
        const updateIconsCallback = () => {
            if (this._enabled) {
                this.updateIcons();
            }
        };
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.CAMERA_CHANGE_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.ISOLATE_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.HIDE_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        this.viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SHOW_EVENT, updateIconsCallback);
        return true;
    }

    unload() {
        // Clean our UI elements if we added any
        if (this._group) {
            this._group.removeControl(this._button);
            if (this._group.getNumberOfControls() === 0) {
                this.viewer.toolbar.removeControl(this._group);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    onToolbarCreated() {
        // Create a new toolbar group if it doesn't exist
        this._group = this.viewer.toolbar.getControl('customExtensions');
        if (!this._group) {
            this._group = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.ControlGroup('customExtensions');
            this.viewer.toolbar.addControl(this._group);
        }

        // Add a new button to the toolbar group
        this._button = new Autodesk.Viewing.UI.Button('IconExtension');
        this._button.onClick = (ev) => {
            this._enabled = !this._enabled;
            this.showIcons(this._enabled);
            this._button.setState(this._enabled ? 0 : 1);

        };
        this._button.setToolTip(this.options.button.tooltip);
        this._button.container.children[0].classList.add('fas', this.options.button.icon);
        this._group.addControl(this._button);
    }

    showIcons(show) {
        console.log('entering into showIcons')
        const $viewer = $('#' + this.viewer.clientContainer.id + ' div.adsk-viewing-viewer');

        // remove previous...
        $('#' + this.viewer.clientContainer.id + ' div.adsk-viewing-viewer label.markup').remove();
        if (!show) return;

        // do we have anything to show?
        if (this._icons === undefined || this.icons === null) return;

        // do we have access to the instance tree?
        const tree = this.viewer.model.getInstanceTree();
        if (tree === undefined) { console.log('Loading tree...'); return; }

        const onClick = (e) => {
            if (this.options.onClick)
                this.options.onClick($(e.currentTarget).data('id'));
        };

        this._frags = {}
        for (var i = 0; i < this._icons.length; i++) {
            // we need to collect all the fragIds for a given dbId
            const icon = this._icons[i];
            this._frags['dbId' + icon.dbId] = []

            // create the label for the dbId
            const $label = $(`
            <label class="markup update" data-id="${icon.dbId}">
                <span class="${icon.css}"> ${icon.label || ''}</span>
            </label>
            `);
            $label.css('display', this.viewer.isNodeVisible(icon.dbId) ? 'block' : 'none');
            $label.on('click', onClick);
            $viewer.append($label);

            // now collect the fragIds
            const _this = this;
            tree.enumNodeFragments(icon.dbId, function (fragId) {
                _this._frags['dbId' + icon.dbId].push(fragId);
                _this.updateIcons(); // re-position of each fragId found
            });
        }
    }

    getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(dbId) {
        var fragList = this.viewer.model.getFragmentList();
        const nodebBox = new THREE.Box3()

        // for each fragId on the list, get the bounding box
        for (const fragId of this._frags['dbId' + dbId]) {
            const fragbBox = new THREE.Box3();
            fragList.getWorldBounds(fragId, fragbBox);
            nodebBox.union(fragbBox); // create a unifed bounding box
        }

        return nodebBox
    }

    updateIcons() {
        for (const label of $('#' + this.viewer.clientContainer.id + ' div.adsk-viewing-viewer .update')) {
            const $label = $(label);
            const id = $label.data('id');

            // get the center of the dbId (based on its fragIds bounding boxes)
            const pos = this.viewer.worldToClient(this.getModifiedWorldBoundingBox(id).center());

            // position the label center to it
            $label.css('left', Math.floor(pos.x - $label[0].offsetWidth / 2) + 'px');
            $label.css('top', Math.floor(pos.y - $label[0].offsetHeight / 2) + 'px');
            $label.css('display', this.viewer.isNodeVisible(id) ? 'block' : 'none');
        }
    }
}

Autodesk.Viewing.theExtensionManager.registerExtension('IconMarkupExtension', IconMarkupExtension);
```

I'm getting no error in the console. And while debugging using console.log found that it's entering into showIcons function. But have no idea if I have to change this a bit to make it work. The dbId given is correct,it's present in the file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To add more, I have tried logging the output of this and also noticed the values are set inside the extension. Attaching screenshot below,
https://ibb.co/zXhtFxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you apply the CSS necessary to correctly display the icons? They can be found [here](https://github.com/augustogoncalves/forge-plant-operation/blob/master/forgeSample/wwwroot/css/index.css#L15)

Because I don’t see those in the style block of the code you posted...

To trouble shoot further check if the labels got rendered to the viewport in the browser’s devtools? If they were check their styling to see if they got obscured or positioned off viewport...